# Reference implementation of vrecpeq_f32 intrinsic?

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, neon

There is `vrecpeq_f32` ARM NEON Intrinsic.

The official explanation for `vrecpeq_f32`: [https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=[Neon]&q=vrecpeq_f32](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D&q=vrecpeq_f32) .

> Floating-point Reciprocal Estimate. This instruction finds an approximate reciprocal estimate for each vector element in the source SIMD&FP register, places the result in a vector, and writes the vector to the destination SIMD&FP register.

However, it is still not accurate for me. Just wondering if we can write a reference implementation in C/C++ that keep exactly the same result as `vrecpeq_f32`?

I've tried calling  `vrecpeq_f32` and get the result:

```c
float32x4_t v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
float32x4_t v_out = vrecpeq_f32(v1);//0.99805, 0.49902, 0.33301, 0.24951
```

Curious why 1's reciprocal is 0.99805 instead of 1.0.

P.S. I'm not interested in how to use NEON intrinsics with some tricks to get better precision reciprocal result, e.g. one or more Newton-Raphson iterations.

Comment: it is documented at [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-03/Shared-Pseudocode/Shared-Functions?lang=en#impl-shared.FPRecipEstimate.2) under **FPRecipEstimate**

Comment: @Frank Oh, I didn't click into that link until you mention. But it seems too long a pseudocode, I thought it would be shorter.

Comment: > Curious why 1's reciprocal is 0.99805 instead of 1.0 . -- I suspect, the result of this instruction is read from a ROM that has a limited set of bins, each bin being used for a range of floating point numbers. IOW, the value of 0.99805 has to be produced and valid not only for the input of 1.0, but also other neighbour values. Hence, the result is an approximation, not an exact value.

Comment: Because it's just an **estimate** as the instruction mnemonic clearly states.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ARM [documention](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-03/Shared-Pseudocode/Shared-Functions?lang=en#impl-shared.FPRecipEstimate.2) provides pseudocode detailing the exact algorithm being performed. Look for `FPRecipEstimate` which uses fixed-point `RecipEstimate`.

That may look like a lot of code, but a big chunk of it is there to handle various edge cases, operation modes, and element sizes.

> Just wondering if we can write a reference implementation in C/C++ that keep exactly the same result as vrecpeq_f32?

Sure! This boils down to bit manipulation after all, so there's no reason it shouldn't be feasible. Converting it to C++ while removing most edge-case handling as well as extended precision mode looks like this: (see on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j89cK9hnc))

**Disclaimer**: This is not a complete implementation of the function, just enough to explore the precision behavior, assuming finite normalized inputs, no special cases. Don't drop this in a codebase expecting it to match the instruction in general.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

// Convenience struct to deal with encoding and decoding ieee754 floats
struct float_parts {
    explicit float_parts(float v);
    explicit operator float() const;

    std::uint32_t sign;
    std::uint32_t fraction;
    std::uint32_t exp;
};

// Adapted from:
// https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-03/Shared-Pseudocode/Shared-Functions?lang=en#impl-shared.FPRecipEstimate.2

// RecipEstimate()
// ===============
// Compute estimate of reciprocal of 9-bit fixed-point number.
//
// a is in range 256 .. 511 representing a number in
// the range 0.5 <= x < 1.0.
// result is in the range 256 .. 511 representing a
// number in the range 1.0 to 511/256
std::uint32_t RecipEstimate(std::uint32_t a) {
    a = a*2+1;
    std::uint32_t b = (1 << 19) / a;
    return ( b + 1) / 2;
}

// FPRecipEstimate()
// =================
float FPRecipEstimate(float operand) {
    // ([...],sign,[...]) = FPUnpack(operand, [...], [...]);
    // fraction = operand<22:0> : Zeros(29);
    // exp = UInt(operand<30:23>);
    float_parts parts{operand};    

    // scaled = UInt('1':fraction<51:44>);
    std::uint32_t scaled = 0x100 | ((parts.fraction >> 15) & 0xFF) ;

    // when 32 result_exp =  253 - exp; // In range 253-254 = -1 to 253+1 = 254
    parts.exp = 253 - parts.exp;

    // // Scaled is in range 256 .. 511 representing a
    // // fixed-point number in range [0.5 .. 1.0].
    // estimate = RecipEstimate(scaled, increasedprecision);
    std::uint32_t estimate = RecipEstimate(scaled);

    // fraction = estimate<11:0> : Zeros(40);
    parts.fraction = (estimate & 0xff ) << 15;

    return float(parts);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) 
              << FPRecipEstimate(1.0f) << "\n"
              << FPRecipEstimate(2.0f) << "\n"
              << FPRecipEstimate(3.0f) << "\n"
              << FPRecipEstimate(4.0f);
}

float_parts::float_parts(float v) {
    std::uint32_t v_bits;
    std::memcpy(&v_bits, &v, sizeof(float));

    sign = (v_bits >> 31) & 0x1;
    fraction = v_bits & ((1 << 23) - 1);
    exp = (v_bits >> 23) & 0xff;
}

float_parts::operator float() const {
    std::uint32_t v_bits = 
        ((sign & 0x1) << 31) |
        (fraction & ((1 << 23) - 1)) |
        ((exp & 0xff) << 23);

    float result;
    std::memcpy(&result, &v_bits, sizeof(float));
    return result;
}
```

Which produces the expected values:

```
0.99805
0.49902
0.33301
0.24951
```